# Comparing the first and last character of a string in python

Tags: python, string, function, character, stringindexoutofbounds

first_and_last function returns True if the first letter of the string is the same as the last letter of the string, False if they’re different, by accessing characters using message[0] or message[-1]. While checking the condition for an empty string I get tihis error:

```
Error on line 2:
    if message[0] == message[1] :
IndexError: string index out of range
```

I dont understand why am I getting this error.
Here's my code below:

```
 def first_and_last(message):
        if message[0] == message[-1] or len(message) == 0:
            return True
     
        else:
            return False
    
    print(first_and_last("else"))
    print(first_and_last("tree"))
    print(first_and_last(""))
```

Comment: You're checking the length after you already tried to access characters in the string that do not exist. Do the length check first.

Comment: Empty string has no indexes. It first checks using indexing leading to an error

Comment: In your first block of code, it's `message[1]`, then `message[-1]` in the second block of code. Which one are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`or` stops evaluating operands on the first truthy operand. Hence, you must check the message length first in order to avoid the indexed access into the empty string:

```
def first_and_last(message):
    if len(message) == 0 or message[0] == message[-1]:
        return True
    return False
```

Or shorter:

```
def first_and_last(message):
    return not message or message[0] == message[-1]
```